# Prove: In a Triangle, $II_1 = a\cdot \sec \frac{A}{2}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Prove that $II_1 = a\cdot \sec \dfrac{A}{2}$.

$I$ is center of incircle, $I_1$ is center of excircle.

What I did is :

Drop $ID \perp AB$, & $I_1F \perp AF$ at $F$ So $ID\parallel I_1F$

$\dfrac{AI}{II_1} = \dfrac{AD}{DF}$

$II_1 = \dfrac{AI \cdot DF}{AD}$

$II_1 = DF \cdot \sec \dfrac{A}{2}$
[image]

What should I do further, or provide me another approach.

Answer (score 3):

Let $T$ be the midpoint of $II_1$.  Show that $\angle BTC=\pi-\angle BAC$ (i.e., $ABTC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral).  Prove that $T$ is the center of the circumcircle of the cyclic quadrilateral $IBI_1C$.  The result follows immediately.

[image]

Comment: I think it is easier if we do the proving part first and then do the showing part second. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You are probably right, but in my proof, both results come up almost simultaneously, so it is kind of hard to specify which order one should try.  If you looked at my edit history, you would see that I swapped these two sentences once.  I wasn't sure which order would be most logical.

Comment: OK. +1 for the nice thought of using the midpoint of $II_1$ as the center.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be the half of perimeter of the triangle (i.e $p = \frac{a+b+c}{2}$). We have $AD = p-a$.

Let compute $BF$. Taking $I_1E \perp BC$ and $I_1G \perp AC$, call that $BE = u$ and $CE = v$, one then has $u+v = a$ and $u + c = v + b$, or $u - v = b-c$.

Thus, $BF = BE = u = \frac{a+b-c}{2} = p - c$.

So, one has $DF = AF - AD = AB + BF - AD = c + p-c -(p-a) = a$.

EDIT: to answer your question in comment, you can draw the line perpendicule to $AB$, $AC$, $BC$ from $I$ and $I_1$. So, you have $2AD = 2p - 2a$, then $AD = p-a$.

Similarly, you have $AF = AG$ or $b+u=c+v$.

Comment: How $AD =p-a$ and $u + c = v + b$, did you answered according to my figure? if not then please add figure also.

Comment: My mistake, I take $I_1G \perp AC$ (you already use $F$).

Answer (score 1):

There is an even simpler way in order to deal with the problem.

Now to find $II_1$, you can also use the following approach :

$$II_1=I_1A-IA$$

$$I_1A= r_1/sin(A/2)$$
and similarly:
$$IA= r/sin(A/2)$$
$$\Rightarrow II_1= r_1/sin(A/2)-r/sin(A/2)$$
Replace $r_1$  by $s\cdot (tan(A/2))$ and $r$ by $(s-a)\cdot \tan(A/2)$

Writing the equation again,
$$ II_1=\frac{s\cdot tan(A/2)}{sin(A/2)}-\frac{(s-a)\cdot \tan(A/2)}{sin(A/2)}$$
$$II_1=\frac{\tan(A/2)}{\sin(A/2)}{a}$$
$$II_1=a/cos(A/2)$$

Comment: If you have any problem in why I have used $r_1=stan(A/2)$ and $r=s-a(tan(A/2))$, then do tell me I would explain that.

Comment: @Ayushakj Thanks for the edit. Did you get the point?

Comment: yes, of course, u did it very easily!!!